# how mount system partition in recovery mode to recover vold.fstab file in / etc

Tags: mount

I have a Chinese tablet Genesis GT 7320 Androd 4.1.2. It is rooted using kingo.
I changed the vold.fstab file on the / etc partition system to vold.fstab.bkp.
The table was locked and did not start anymore. Action or recovery mode by pressing the
power and volume buttons above. I have access installed on the macbook and access to the tablet
through the adb shell. After running commands with busybox. I'm a layman and I took
time to discover the adb and busybox commands. However, I can't
access a / etc partition system to rename the vold.fstab.bkp file to simply
vold.fstab. I saw on the internet that you need to mount a system partition. I tried several
commands I found on the internet, but I didn't get results. Below are some of the directories I have access with adb shell. Can someone help me?

## busybox ls

cache                     init.rc                   sbin
charger                   mnt                       sys
data                      proc                      system
default.prop              res                       tmp
dev                       rk29-ipp.ko               ueventd.goldfish.rc
etc                       rk29-ipp.ko.3.0.36+       ueventd.rc
init                      rk30xxnand_ko.ko.3.0.36+  ueventd.rk30board.rc
init.bootmode.emmc.rc     rk30xxnand_ko.ko.3.0.8+
init.bootmode.unknown.rc  root

## busybox ls /dev/block

loop0       loop5       mmcblk0p2   mtdblock10  mtdblock6
loop1       loop6       mmcblk0p3   mtdblock2   mtdblock7
loop2       loop7       mtd         mtdblock3   mtdblock8
loop3       mmcblk0     mtdblock0   mtdblock4   mtdblock9
loop4       mmcblk0p1   mtdblock1   mtdblock5   platform

## busybox ls /sys/block

loop0       loop4       mmcblk0     mtdblock2   mtdblock6
loop1       loop5       mtdblock0   mtdblock3   mtdblock7
loop2       loop6       mtdblock1   mtdblock4   mtdblock8
loop3       loop7       mtdblock10  mtdblock5   mtdblock9

Comment: `mount -w /system` then `rm /system/etc/vold.fstab` and `mv /system/etc/vold.fstab.bkp vold.fstab` (with busybox prefix maybe)
https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GNU_Core_Utilities_commands (please also read Related questions on the right) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: The system showed the following message when I used busybox mount -w / system: mount: cannot read / etc / fstab: No such file or directory

Comment: which recovery do you have? check /system is already mounted with `mount` or `df` and remount it writeable `mount -o rw,remount /system` or `find /dev/block -name system` and `mount -w <partition> /system`

Comment: I used the guidance, but the system issued the following messages when I typed the commands below:

# busybox mount -o rw, remount /system
mount: mounting remount on /system failed: No such file or directory

# busybox ls /dev/block               

loop0
loop1
loop2
loop3
loop4
loop5
loop6
loop7
mmcblk0
mmcblk0p1
mmcblk0p2
mmcblk0p3
mtd
mtdblock0
mtdblock1
mtdblock10
mtdblock2
mtdblock3
mtdblock4
mtdblock5
mtdblock6
mtdblock7
mtdblock8
mtdblock9
platform

Comment: Hello, is android system recovery version v4.2.41

Comment: I typed the command busybox find / dev / block -name system and the system issued the following message:  /dev/block/mtd/by-name/system

Comment: Congratulations!!! It worked!! Thank you very much for your help.